# Disabled internet connection on host breaks docker network

Tags: docker, networking

My system:
Docker version 19.03.1;
docker-compose version 1.18.0; 
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I have two linked docker containers (a server container + mongodb container) that are launched with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - adapt-author-0.9.0:/data/db
    networks:
      author_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.0.100

  author:
    container_name: author
    image: adapt-author:0.9.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      author_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.0.200
    working_dir: /opt/adapt_authoring
    entrypoint: ["node", "server"]

networks:
  author_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.10.0.0/24

volumes:
  adapt-author-0.9.0:
    external:
      name: adapt-author-0.9.0
```

As long as the host is connected to the internet, launching the containers works like expected. If the internet connection of the host is dropped, it doesn't.

How can I run the above scenario without established internet connection of the host?

Comment: What specific actions disconnect the host's network connection?  What error do you get?

Comment: (You should be able to remove about half of this `docker-compose.yml` file without any practical changes; remove all of the manual `networks:` settings, the `links:`, manual `container_name:` overrides, and (presumably) the `working_dir:` and `entrypoint:` settings that duplicate what's in the Dockerfile.  Including a smaller [mcve] in the question would make it more approachable.)

Comment: @DavidMaze: Manual disconnection (Ubuntu network manager) or booting the computer without availabel internet. 
Errors (docker ps -a):

adapt-author:0.9.0   "node server" About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago